# rsync remote to local - Unexpected remote arg

Tags: bash, sudo, rsync

I'm trying to assemble an rsync command in a bash variable and then execute it.
It looks something like this:

```
CMD="$RSYNC -a $REMOTE $LOCAL $LINK_DEST"
```

It gets executed like this

```
RSYNC_RESULT=$($CMD)
```

This works fine until I try to add add `--rsync-path="sudo /usr/local/bin/rsync"` to the mix (so that rsync runs as root on the remote).

```
RSYNC_PATH='--rsync-path="sudo /usr/local/bin/rsync"'
CMD="$RSYNC -a $RSYNC_PATH $REMOTE $LOCAL $LINK_DEST"
```

Now I get an error

> Unexpected remote arg: user@remote.local:/Users/user/files/
>   rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1343) [sender=3.1.2]

I'm fairly certain it's connected to the quoting in the `$RSYNC_PATH` var and/or the `$($CMD)` bit, because I can paste the resulting command into a shell and it runs successfully.

Any ideas what I can do to make this work?

Comment: I substituted `$($CMD)` for `eval $CMD` and it seems to work. Anyone know why?

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...to avoid [the security issues associated with `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), use an array -- not a string -- to store an argument list.

Comment: A more correct invocation might look like `rsync_path=( --rsync-path="sudo /usr/local/bin/rsync" ); cmd=( rsync -a "${rsync_path[@]}" "$remote" "$local" "$link_dest" ); "${cmd[@]}"`

Comment: ...re: the use of lower-case vs all-caps variable names, see relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities*; keep in mind that setting regular shell variables overwrites any preexisting like-named environment variable.

Comment: Thanks Charles, works perfectly.  Can I mark a comment as a solution?

Comment: No need -- the comments just summarize advice from the linked duplicates; since it's closed as a duplicate, the question is marked as not needing a separate answer.